# executing a .sql file through ubuntu command line for postgres

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have installed postgresql on ubuntu using:

```
$ sudo apt install postgresql
```

Now, I have a series of sql queries I would like to fire to create schemas and users and tables etc. I have put those queries in a .sql file as below:

```
$ sudo nano postgressetup.sql
CREATE SCHEMA schma;
CREATE USER a2i WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres TO schma;
```

This file has all the queries. I tried something like:

```
$ psql -U postgres -d postgres -a -f postgressetup.sql
```

and received error:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I want to know the way I can execute this .sql file.
**Note:** I've just installed postgres and no further operation is done on it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+Peer+authentication+failed+for+user+%22postgres%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command explicitly providing db context user

`sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d postgres -a -f postgressetup.sql`